# Creating a sequence of unique random digits

Tags: arrays, perl, foreach, unique

I have the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.22.0;

# Generating random seed using 
# Programming Perl p. 955
srand( time() ^ ($$ + ($$ << 15 ) ) );

# Generating code that could have duplicates
my @code = (
    (int(rand(9)) + 1),
    (int(rand(9)) + 1),
    (int(rand(9)) + 1),
    (int(rand(9)) + 1)
);

# Trying to remove duplicates and choosing the unique code
my %seen = ();
my @unique = grep { ! $seen{ $_ }++ } @code;
say @unique;
```

I am generating a list of four random numbers, and I need to make sure that all four numbers are unique. I am able to scrape out the unique numbers but it is not always maintaining a scalar length of 4.

My initial thoughts were to do a `foreach` loop checking to see if each element is the same, but there has to be a quicker way to do this.

This is my initial thought (not using the unique set)

```
my $index = 0
foreach my $element (@code) {
    if ($element == $code[index]) {  
        # repopulate @code at said element
        $code[$index] = (int(rand(9)) + 1);
    }
    $index++;
 }
```

However, I believe that this might give me the same issue in that there might be duplicates.

Is there a quicker way to do this while maintaining four numbers in my array that are all unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a list of four unique non-zero decimal digits, use `shuffle` from [`List::Util`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) and pick the first four

Like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use List::Util 'shuffle';

my @unique = (shuffle 1 .. 9)[0..3];

say "@unique";
```

**output**

```
8 5 1 4
```

There's no need to seed the random number generator as Perl does it for you. Only use `srand` if you need a *repeatable* random sequence

---

**Update**

Here's another way that's similar to what you already had. Essentially it just keeps making random numbers until it has four different ones

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %unique;
++$unique{int(rand 9) + 1} while keys %unique < 4;

say join ' ', keys %unique;
```

Comment: Also use `srand` if you fork.

Answer (score 0):

@Boromir gave you what is probably the cleanest solution. If you do need to use `rand()`, just make sue no duplicates are saved in the first place instead of removing them later:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.22.0;
# Generating random seed using 
# Programming Perl p. 955
srand(time()^($$+($$<<15)));

#Generating code that can't have duplicates
my %seen = ();
while (scalar(keys(%seen)!=4)) {
    $seen{int(rand(9)) + 1}++
}
say keys %seen;
```